# Update SharepointList only in power apps

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps

We just created a rather complex power app which will be used by numerous users (in the company). Although there will be a small team who will handle over viewing the inputs from these users.

The goal is to restrict the users to go into the sharepoint site and delete or edit any records which them or others created. We cannot use any other datasource only sp lists.

I tried creating permissions for specific groups but they don't seem to be working properly.

thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [item level permission](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/05/sharepoint-online-set-item-level-permission-in-list.html#:%7E:text=How%20to%20enable%20item%2Dlevel%20permissions%20in%20SharePoint%20Online%3F&text=Click%20on%20%E2%80%9CAdvanced%20Settings.%E2%80%9D,can%20set%20Item%2Dlevel%20settings.) on SharePoint, I believe this is what you need

In addition Take a [look here as well](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Powerapps-and-Sharepoint-Online-Permissions/m-p/850520/highlight/true#M270338).

Answer (score 0):

Follow below process:

1. Create two groups in SharePoint site - Admins and Normal users
2. On item creation in SharePoint list, run a Power automate flow which will grant Full control access to Admins and only Read permissions to normal users (or just the user who created list item - as per your requirements).

Follow below article for setting permissions for individual list items using power automate: [Set Item Level Permission in SharePoint List using Power Automate](https://www.netwoven.com/2020/11/03/set-item-level-permission-in-sharepoint-list-using-power-automate/)